# My javascript while loop stops after the first prompt

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

Can someone please tell me why my script wont go to the 2th question?
i have checked the firefox console it does not show any syntactical errors so I'm kind of stuck here.

thank you in advance.

here is my script:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
var vraag = new Array();
var cantwoord = new Array();

vraag[1] = "8x4=? ";
vraag[2] = "8/4=? ";
vraag[3] = "16x4=? ";

cantwoord[1]= "32";
cantwoord[2]= "2";
cantwoord[3]= "64";

function toets(index)
{
antwoord = prompt(vraag[index]);
if(antwoord == cantwoord[index])
{
return ("Correct");
}   
else
{
return ("Fout");    
}

}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var doorgaan = true;
var index = 0;
while(doorgaan)
{
index++;
resultaat = toets(index);
doorgaan = confirm(reultaat+" Wil je doorgaan ?");
if(index==3) break; 
}


//]]>
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try adding a console.log just before `index++`.

Comment: That typo ("reultaat" instead of "resultaat" in the call to `confirm()`) causes an error that's logged to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these modifications:

```
//...
var resultaat = toets(index); // Add var before variable
doorgaan = confirm(resultaat+" Wil je doorgaan ?"); // reultaat --> resultaat 
if(index==3) break; 
//...
```

Comment: think my firefox is conspiring against me together with html

Comment: After loading your HTML press Ctrl+Shift+J and check out the last errors. I bet your can debug many problems. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much everyone you are the best thing that ever happed to me hahahahahha!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a no problem in your code except one spelling mistake..It should be

```
resultaat = toets(index);
doorgaan = confirm(resultaat+" Wil je doorgaan ?");
```